# Implementation of MSIL as pure assembly?

Tags: .net, assembly, bytecode, cil

Recently, I got interest in assembly language in general. In doing so, I have also grown interested in the concept of bytecode. So I was rather interested when I looked into Microsoft's .NET, and found that it used a sort of pseudo-assembly to create its own bytecode. However, I was really impressed by the assembly language itself. It seems like a sort of higher level assembly to me.

My question is, could this be implemented into pure assembly, as in, compiled native code rather than JIT/interpreted .NET bytecode? Would it be wise to attempt such an endevour and what would be the benefits?

Comment: with the ngen tool http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.71).aspx it's not suggested anyway because the executable will not be optimized for the machine where it may run later

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Yes, I was aware of this, and similar tools, but obviously, its uses are very limited and propietary.

Comment: So your question is.. are there any non-proprietary MSIL->ASM converters/compilers?

Comment: Perhaps... But that's a very "lazy" way of looking at it. I guess the question is more of "is there an assembler that can take this crud in?" I'd much rather have the second question answered as well.

Comment: Well, the lazy answer is using ilasm to assemble MSIL into a .NET PE file.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: As far as I can't tell no there aren't. And you may guess yourself why. Microsoft owns the control on MSIL and everything orbiting around the .NET framework -including the OS itself. The only third party "framework" I know about is Mono and it's just something to run .net application out of the Windows OS. Nobody would have any interest in maintaining such a big monster with no real benefits. Anyway talking in abstract ... using managed code has its own advantages over the unmanaged world. Sometimes simply it's nonsense compiling an application on native code.

Comment: yes ilasm...I told ngen .. apologize, they are 2 totally different tools.

Comment: You may also want to look at Mono AOT

Answer (score 1):

Converting CIL to machine-specific assembly is possible, to some extent.

Marc Gravell has mentioned Mono AOT in the comments, that's one option. As listed on the [Mono AOT](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) page, if you use full AOT (no runtime IL interpretation whatsoever), there are some restrictions on what you can and cannot do. Otherwise, some IL that can be converted to machine code is, and the rest is interpreted at runtime just as it normally would be.

There's also [IL2CPU created by and for the Cosmos project](https://cosmos.codeplex.com/), which creates an entire operating system in C#. If there's no hosting operating system, there's no .NET Framework, and they have little choice but to translate the IL to machine code. IL2CPU has its limits too, but I don't know of a complete listing.

But ultimately, for the vast majority of .NET programs, the advantages are few. Your programs won't run significantly faster, you make your program hard to debug (is there a bug in your program, or in your IL translator?), and if your installation ends up including bits of the .NET Framework itself, security updates don't apply to your copy of those bits. So, don't do it, unless you really know what you're doing.